# jqplot replot(options) with options object created externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I've got a page with a jqplot, which updates every second. The data for it and other elements comes from an external source as a JSON object. When updating the graph I not only set new 'data' but also new options. The object containing the options is created on the server side and may look like this:

```
{
    "UID371": 0,
    "UID435": false,
    "UID3649": {
        "data": [[[6352, 0.8056758485372573],
                  [6401.5, 8.151520080670746],
                  [6451, 9.539407751657835]],
                 [[6352, 0.08951953872636191],
                  [6401.5, 5.448176141292487],
                  [6451, 5.559745244047493]]],
        "series": [
            {
                "label": "Plot 0",
                "yaxis": "yaxis"
            },
            {
                "label": "Plot 1",
                "yaxis": "yaxis"
            }
        ],
        "axes": {
            "xaxis": {
                "label": "Time",
                "min": 6352,
                "max": 6451,
                "labelRenderer": "$.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer"
            },
            "yaxis": {
                "label": "Amplitude",
                "min": 0,
                "max": 10,
                "labelRenderer": "$.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In javascript I simply call the replot() function like this:

```
function GetData(){
    $.get("GetData?Page=Main", function(res){
            plot3649.replot(res.UID3649);
          }, "json");
};
```

The problem I'm having is that I can only set labelRenderer as a string because I don't have access to "$.jqplot" when I'm creating the object. "labelRenderer": "$.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer" causes an error in jqplot. How can I get that working?

Comment: I can work around it by doing this:
res.UID3649.axes.xaxis.labelRenderer= $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer;
before calling replot() but it means hard-coding the renderer in js